# PostgreSQL Bulk Image Insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, bulkinsert, dynamic-sql

I have 194 `images` in one folder which I want to upload in `PostgreSQL` Table. I am using a `SQL` command -

```
INSERT INTO Uploaded_images (img)
VALUES ( bytea_import('C:\300dpi jpegs\Vintage.jpg'))
```

How can I upload all the images in a one command.

Or is there any other way to bulk insert imaged into table?

Comment: loop in dir result and insert with existing command

Answer (score 2):

loop in dir result and insert with existing command:

```
for /r %i in (*) do psql -c "INSERT INTO Uploaded_images (img) VALUES (bytea_import('%i'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Move image folder to PostgreSQL data directory*( Ex. `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data`).

`E:\pgData96\imgdir\` -  `'E:\pgData96'` is my PostgreSQL Data directory and
`'imgdir'` consists images to be inserted

*[`pg_ls_dir`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html) :

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory
>   can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
>   directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting
>   for log files. Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

```
SELECT format('insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import(''%s''));', ('E:\pgData96\imgdir\' || pg_ls_dir)) a
FROM pg_ls_dir('E:\pgData96\imgdir\');
```

Above select dynamically creates insert statement for all images in folder `E:\pgData96\imgdir\`.

Ex.

```
"insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import('E:\pgData96\imgdir\12.2.17. - 5.png'));"
"insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import('E:\pgData96\imgdir\15 - 49.png'));"
"insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import('E:\pgData96\imgdir\16 - 1.png'));"
"insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import('E:\pgData96\imgdir\16 - 20 (1).png'));"
```

Dynamically execute insert statement using the following SQL script

```
do $$

declare rw record;

begin
    for rw in -- loops through each row in the resultset

    SELECT format('insert into imgs(img) values(bytea_import(''%s''));', ('E:\pgData96\imgdir\' || pg_ls_dir)) a
    FROM pg_ls_dir('E:\pgData96\imgdir\') loop

    execute rw.a; -- executes row(insert statement)
end

loop;end;$$;
```

---